# The dangers of web apps or websites maliciously accessing my clipboard?

Tags: security

Is there a danger of my clipboard data being harvested by a web app or site that I visit?

I would like to stay safe, but I want to keep JavaScript enabled to give a better user experience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most modern browsers will not allow JavaScript to access your clipboard without at least a warning. It's plugins such as Flash that you need to worry about.

For more information, see [MozillaZine's article](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Granting_JavaScript_access_to_the_clipboard) which states:

> By default, JavaScript is not allowed
>   to read or set your clipboard data for
>   security and privacy reasons. This is
>   because websites scripts can erase and
>   replace what you currently have in
>   your clipboard (data loss issue) and
>   they can read whatever you have in
>   your clipboard (security and privacy
>   issue); as such, you should grant
>   access with caution.

There are extensions such as AllowClipboard Helper for Firefox which should let you decide exactly which sites have access to your clipboard.

Comment: or java applets ...

Comment: @akira Untrusted Java applets should only get clipboard data if you explicitly copy/paste in that applet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is definitely a danger that websites can access your clipboard data.

On desktop browsers, it may be true that this can happen only if you have granted permission or dismissed a warning dialog.  But while the permission may have been granted at a particular moment  for a particular purpose, the permission lingers beyond that particular moment and purpose, granting the website the ability to read your clipboard whenever the document is focused.

So for instance:

- you grant a web page permission to paste a cat image to a meme generator.
- you change tabs to your bank's website, and copy/paste your password to login.
- you return to the cat page to see the meme.
- The meme generator site can see the bank password in the clipboard contents.

For mobile devices, it appears that the clipboard is accessible to any application

https://avoidthehack.com/how-secure-is-your-copied-text